# Get socket object

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm using socket.io together with redis and I need to get the socket object since there's data I need to access that's added during the middleware.

When I do this:

```
const { socketServer } = require('../../socket/socket');
const allSockets = await socketServer.myNamespace.adapter.sockets(new Set());
```

I only get the socket id's, not the socket object. How can I get the socket object?

Using:

socket.io: 4.0.1.
socket.io-redis: 6.1.0

**Update**

```
const socketServer = {
    _initialized: false,
    _IO: null,
    _myNamespace: null,
    get IO() {
        if (!socketServer._initialized) throw new Error('socketServer.create not called!');
        return socketServer._IO;
    },
    get myNamespace() {
        if (!socketServer._initialized) throw new Error('socketServer.create not called!');
        return socketServer._myNamespace;
    },
    create: (server) => {
        const { initMyNamespace } = require('./setupHandler');

        socketServer._IO = io(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

        const redisPort = config.get('redisPort');
        const redisHost = config.get('redisHost');

        const redisConnection = redisAdapter({ host: redisHost, port: redisPort });

        socketServer._IO.adapter(redisConnection);

        // inits
        socketServer._myNamespace = socketServer._IO.of('myNamespace');

        // Middlewares
        socketServer._myNamespace.use(auth);

        socketServer._myNamespace.on('connection', function (socket) {
            initMyNamespace(socket);
        });
    
        socketServer._initialized = true;
    },
};
```

In another file in an api call:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { socketServer } = require('../../socket/socket');

    let selectedSockets = [];
    const allSockets = await socketServer.myNamespace.adapter.sockets(new Set());
    
    const userCoordinates = req.body.coordinates;
    for (const currentSocketObj of allSockets) {
        if (isNear(userCoordinates, currentSocketObj.user.coordinates)) {
            const distanceToLocation = distanceCalc(userCoordinates, currentSocketObj.user.coordinates);
            currentSocketObj.distanceToLocation = distanceToLocation;
            selectedSockets.push(currentSocketObj);
        }
    }
    
    for (const currentSocketObj of selectedSockets) {
        currentSocketObj.emit('testing123', {distance: currentSocketObj.distanceToLocation} );
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of socket.io are you using (some APIs changes in v4 is why I'm asking)?

Comment: @jfriend00 socket.io: 4.0.1.     socket.io-redis: 6.1.0

Comment: When you say you want to get "the socket object", what do you mean.  If this is a server, there are N connected sockets at any given time.  Also, are you using the redis adapter and socket.io clustering?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to access the socket item that has the handshake. I'm using the redis adapter. I will be using socket.io clustering in the future

Comment: Please show the context of the code where you're trying to access the socket because it is probably already in scope as `socket`.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's in another file. So I bascially setup the socketserver then export it so it's accessible in other files

Comment: Well, we need to see that code and see the code where you want the `socket`.  You probably just need to pass it.  It will be available on scope in the original callback.  If you're then calling some other function from there in a different file/scope, you need to pass the `socket` with that function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In socket.io v4, you can do:

```
// return all Socket instances
const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();
```

or, if you have a socketID, you can get the socket for that with this:

```
// return all Socket instances in the "room1" room of the main namespace
const sockets = await io.in(theSocketID).fetchSockets();
```

Both calls return an iterable of sockets.

---

If (according to your comment), you're trying to get a specific socket that is in the process of connecting, then that `socket` should already be in scope based on the event handler that got you called in the first place.  If you show that code in context, we can probably show you were the `socket` reference is in that.

Comment: Can I use `io.fetchSockets();` when using redis?

Comment: @Jessica - I believe so, but this isn't the right solution to the problem that you've now described.  You just need to pass the `socket` that was already in scope in the original event handler to your function in your other module.  There's no point in using `fetchSockets()` to get an entire list of sockets.  That won't tell you which socket is responsible for the current handshake.  If you show us your code in both modules, we can help precisely.  Please stop resisting showing your actual code - that's what we need to help you.

Comment: Ur right, just didn't want to clunk up the question... Posted the setup code for socket. The code where I want to get all sockets is in an api request. I will be sending each socket specific data based on it's data inside

Comment: @Jessica - I don't follow what exact code you want to reference the `socket` from within and how that code gets called.

Comment: @Jessica - An, you are never clunking up the question by including your code.  In fact, you should  always include your code here.  To the contrary, questions about code must include your code.  We can provide faster and more accurate answers when we see your code.  If you had included all the relevant code when you first posted the question, we probably would have been done an hour ago.  I still need to see and understand the code where you want to access the `socket`.

Comment: Yes, I agree! My apologies for not posting it all at first. Thanks for pointing it out. I just updated it with the complete code. Hoping it now makes more sense :)

Comment: @Jessica - And, on what line of code are you trying to get access to what socket?  Is the code that starts with `let selectedSockets = [];` inside of an API call or inside of some other function.  If so, please show that and show how it's called and show exactly where you're trying to get a specific socket and how you would know which of the many connected sockets you're trying to get?

Comment: So in 2 places. 1: In the first loop I need to add `distanceToLocation` field. And in the last loop, I need to emit a message to the socket users that are nearby a certain location. So that's why I need to get all sockets from `myNamespace` and only emit to certain ones.

Comment: @Jessica - As my original answer shows, you can use `.fetchSockets()` to get sockets from a namespace.  Examples in the doc right [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespace-fetchSockets).  If you need further help, please explain what part of that doc page you don't understand or isn't meeting your needs and why.

Comment: @Jessica - Note that it looks to me like the first `for (const currentSocketObj of selectedSockets) {` should be iterating `allSockets` and `allSockets` should come from a call to `.fetchSockets()`.

Comment: Great catch Thanks! Do u know if my setup of socketServer is correct and ideal?

Comment: @Jessica - I don't see anything in your setup that's off.  Looks fine to me.  I don't generally try and abstract and hide things that are simple to use on the io server object already like you are doing as that just makes the caller have to know/learn a new API rather than using the completely satisfactory socket.io API that's already there, but that's a matter of design opinion.